# Will ubuntu get better at supporting notebooks with switchable graphics?

Tags: graphics, fglrx

I own a Dell Vostro 3560 with a AMD Radeon 7670M. With my limited knowledge, I couldn't manage to get Ubuntu running on it [(I asked for help here back then)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232781/fan-running-uncontrolled-on-dell-vostro-3560-under-ubuntu-12-10).
Reluctantly, I made the switch to windows. That was in January 2013.

I am curious if I can expect future versions of ubuntu to work better on it?

Answer (score 0):

I personally have Ubuntu on a laptop with switchable graphics, and Catalyst Control Center works fine for switching between cards and I don't have any graphical issues. Did you try installing the proprietary AMD driver? (see [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx%22here%22))